# React - add or remove class on click

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to add the "active" class on the hamburger div when its clicked so my sidebar to be visible  when its clicked on smaller devices and remove the class "active" it from the  close div. I understand that I have to use usestate but I'm not sure how because my code keeps breaking.

my code

```
import StyledLink from './styled'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SideBar = () =>{
const [active, setActive] = useState(false)

      return (
        <>

          <div className={active ? ".wrapper" : ".wrapper.active"}>
              <div className="sidebar">
                <div className="bg-shadow"></div>
                    <div className="sidebar_inner">
                    <div className="close">
                    <i className="fas fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div className="profile_info">
                       <div className="profile_img">
                         <img src="" alt="profile_pic"/>
                          </div>
                         <div className="profile_data">
                        <div className="name">Tina Makri </div>
                        <div className="role">Full-Stack Developer </div>

                     </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="sidebar_menu">
                    <StyledLink to="/">
                    <div className="title">Home </div>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink to="/about " >
                    <div className="title">About</div>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink to="/project">
                    <div className="title">Projects </div>
                    </StyledLink>

                    <StyledLink to="/contact">
                    <div className="title">Contact </div>
                    </StyledLink>
                    </ul>
                      </div>
              </div>
              <div className="main_container">
              <div className="top_navbar">
                <div className="hamburger" >
                    <div className="hamburger__inner " >

                  <button id="menuToggler" onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>  <i className="fas fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                    </div>

                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }



export default SideBar;
```

and my css

```
*{
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .sidebar{
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar_inner{
  width :250px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.main_container{

  margin-left:250px;
  width: calc(100%-250px);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper .sidebar_inner .profile_info{
  padding: 30px 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .sidebar_inner .profile_info .profile_img{
  width: 125px;
  margin:0 auto 15px;
}
.wrapper .sidebar_inner .profile_info .profile_img img{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.wrapper .sidebar_inner .profile_info .profile_data .name{
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
}
.wrapper .sidebar_inner .profile_info .profile_data .role{
  font-weight: 300;
  color:#88a3d0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}


.wrapper .main_container .top_navbar{
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 60px;
  background-color:  #923baa;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:250px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.wrapper .main_container .top_navbar .hamburger{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;

}
.wrapper .main_container .top_navbar .hamburger .fa-bars{
  color:white !important;
  font-size:25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,9%);
}
.wrapper .main_container .top_navbar .hamburger .fa-bars:hover{
  opacity:0.5;
}

.wrapper .close{
  position: absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:15px;
  font-size:25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
display: none;
}
.wrapper.active{
  right: 100%;
}
.wrapper .close:hover{
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px){
  .wrapper .sidebar .sidebar_inner{
    left:-100%;
  }
  .wrapper .main_container,
  .wrapper .main_container .top_navbar{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  .wrapper .main_container .top_navbar{
    left:0;
  }
  .wrapper .main_container .top_navbar .hamburger,
  .wrapper .close {
    display: block;
  }
  .wrapper.active .sidebar .sidebar__inner{
    left:0;
  }

}
```

Comment: Try `const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!active)
  }` `onClick={handleToggle}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className={active ? ".wrapper" : ".wrapper.active"}>
```

should instead be

```
<div className={active ? "wrapper" : "wrapper active"}>
```

or better yet

```
<div className={'wrapper ' + (active ? '' : 'active'}>
```

(Although just to clarify, this would add the `"active"` class when `active` is false! Did you mean to swap the inline-if?)

Comment: thank you for your answer ! But still it doesn't seem to work. When i press the button the sidebar doesn't show .

Comment: What are the classes before and after you click the button on that div?

Comment: Before is the " .wrapper", so on screens smaller than 800px my sidebar is not visible with the left:-100%. So i want when I press the button the sidebar to be visible with the ".wrapper active"

Comment: I mean can you check the element itself and see what the classes actually are before and after you click the button?

Comment: before iits "wrapper" and after its "wrapper active" so I guess the problem is on my css?

Comment: Yeah, might be. You can use Inspect Element to see what styles are being applied with the wrapper and active classes (if any).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using here:

```
.wrapper
```

```
.wrapper.active
```

are *selector strings* - which, for example, would be used inside CSS rules, or by `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` or jQuery. A dot before a word indicates that you're selecting a class with that particular word.

```
.foo {
  color: red
}
```

will make the following element red:

```
<div class="foo">text</div>
```

The class attribute in the HTML should not have any periods in it - the period is only for selector strings, to indicate that you're selecting a class. This:

```
<div className={active ? ".wrapper" : ".wrapper.active"}>
```

needs to be fixed to

```
<div className={active ? "wrapper active" : "wrapper"}>
```